# Initialize Array in a Node

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, insertion-sort

I have an `ArrayList v1` of unsorted `int`s, that one by one, I am trying to insert into an `array` in a `Node` by ordered insertion method.

This is my code from my main method, taking an `int` from the unsorted `ArrayList` and putting it into the parameter of my `orderedInsert()` method:

```
DoublyLinkedList list1 = new DoublyLinkedList();
for (int j = 0; j < v1.getSize(); j++) {
    int num = v1.get(j);
    list1.orderedInsert(MAXSIZE, num);
}
System.out.println(list1);
```

But my `orderedInsert()` method is a mess, because I am not sure if I am suppose to return a `Node`, a `DoublyLinkedList` or void, and how to initialize an `array` in a `Node`.

```
public static void orderedInsert(int size, int num) { 
    int[] array list = new int[size];
    if (first == null) {
        list[0] = num;
        Node newNode = new Node(list);  //<--- I'm very unsure if this is right 
    }  
    else {
        int spot = size -1; 
        while(spot>0 && list[spot] > num) {
            spot--;
        }
        list[spot+1] = num;
        Node newNode = new Node(list);
    }
}//ordInsert
```

**Edit:** The reason that I am even putting these int values in a Node, is because I am performing a `Bucket Sort` on them later and will eventually have to split the `Node` based on the max size that each array can hold. So, if I am inserting the 9th `int` for an array in a `Node` that can only hold 8, I will split these in half and have a `Node` of 5, and another of 4.

Comment: And your question exactly is...?

Comment: @Turing85 Their question is how to initialize Array in a Node.

Comment: Yes, that is my question. How do I initialize an array in a Node, and then after it is sorted, print the list back in the main method (what is my return value)?